# Can you display a WebRTC call / Web-App on a Smart Displays?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

At work, we're trying to evaluate if we can have our Web-App go a step further by integrating Google Assistant in it and be able to use it with a Smart Dislay (Lenovo 10" is currently targeted).

In 2 words, our app allow to call (visio) people through WebRTC, and we need that call displayed on the Lenovo.

I personally never integrated an app with Google Assistant, so I'm turning to you guys to avoid losing times if it's not possible at all.

I saw Interactive Canvas, it could have been an option, but by reading the Google doc, it seems like it's reserved for games right now.

Thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 0):

The Interactive Canvas feature is only for games, so non-game applications won't be approved.

Beyond that, while a lot of web features are supported, I don't think WebRTC will be. In particular, [capturing audio and video are blocked](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas/web-apps#guidelines_and_restrictions) in the web container so you wouldn't be able to use this approach.